# Difference between void proc and void proc with discard

Tags: nim-lang

Given the following two procs:

```
proc firstOne(): void =
    echo "X"

proc secondOne(): void =
    echo "X"
    discard
```

What functional difference, if any, is there between them? And if they are the same, what is the purpose of discard if void type discards the result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `discard` in the second procedure is superfluous. A `discard` without an argument is simply a no-op. It is normally used (like `pass` in Python) where the language syntax requires a statement, but where you don't want to do anything. An example would be an empty procedure:

```
proc doNothing() =
  discard
```

You can still add `discard` even where it is not syntactically necessary because as a no-op it doesn't do anything.

This is different from `discard` with an argument, whose purpose is to call a function for its side effects and ignore the result.